# Trying to test send emails on localhost -> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, phpmailer

Im trying to test my emails functions in localhost with phpmailer class.

But I´m getting this error: **SMTP Error: Could not authenticate..**

And this error its because I dont have a localhost email configured.

I already did this configuration in my Xampp php.ini to try test emails on localhost:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
 smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myemail@hotmail.com
```

But its not working, Somebody there knows How to do this work on windows 8 with xampp?

```
<?php
    define('MAILUSER','myemail@hotmail.com');
    define('MAILPASS','');
    define('MAILPORT','587');
    define('MAILHOST','smtp.live.com');
    define('SITENAME', 'Site Name');    

        function sendMail($subject,$message,$sender,$senderName,$destination,$destinationName, $reply = NULL, $replyNome = NULL){

            require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php'); 

            $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
            $mail->IsSMTP(); 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
            $mail->IsHTML(true);

            $mail->Host = MAILHOST; 
            $mail->Port = MAILPORT; 
            $mail->Username = MAILUSER; 
            $mail->Password = MAILPASS; 

            $mail->From = utf8_decode($sender); 
            $mail->FromName = utf8_decode($senderName); 

            if($reply != NULL){
                $mail->AddReplyTo(utf8_decode($reply),utf8_decode($replyNome)); 
            }

            $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($assunto); 
            $mail->Body = utf8_decode($mensagem); 
            $mail->AddAddress(utf8_decode($destino),utf8_decode($destinationName)); 

            if($mail->Send()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }   
    ?>
```

Here I send the email:

```
$msg = 'hello';
sendMail('Sent email!',$msg,MAILUSER,SITENAME,$assoc['email'],$assoc['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your SMTP configuration needs to be updated? See this article about the Hotmail SMTP settings:

http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-hotmail

Comment: Thank you, now I get this error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: Correct, you're still going need to use the correct authentication needed for Hotmail/Live. You'll need to research the exact auth credentials needed.

Comment: I already read all the documentation you give me and I´m doing like It was there, Using smtp.live.com as mailhost and por 25 and my email to receive the emails and my password of that email..but it gives me this error!

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest. At least ensure you're specifying your FULL email address `foo@hotmail.com` value in the `username` field and not just the `foo` part.

Comment: Thank you, and yes I´m specifying full email adress! Well, I´ll continue searching trying to find the light..lol!